# pjax - the current node list is empty

Tags: pjax

I am using pjax 2.0.0 by cdn and after adding
this line of code     $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container');
and when I go to check the header this is Request Url
http://laravelclear.dev/replace-page?_pjax=
and my response is 500 the current node list is empty 
I have searched alot please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of search in many site and my problem was asked but there was no answer for this question for  and  finally I found a way for using pjax and my problem was crawler version for laravel middleware pjax I used 
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-pjax  this one and for crawler I used this command
composer require spatie/crawler
and this is working fine
I hope this can help others.